# NHibernate 3.3 query caching throwing exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, caching

I recently upgraded our app to use NHibernate 3.3 and wanted to enable caching.

We're in a multitenant enviroment, so I want each session factory to keep a region for each client.

Here's my NHibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
    <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2005Dialect</property>
    <property name="cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.use_second_level_cache">true</property>
    <property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheProvider,NHibernate.Caches.SysCache</property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=localhost; database=test;user=test; password=test;</property>
    <property name="show_sql">false</property>
    <property name="command_timeout">1000</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and in our session factory generator...

```
 private static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory(string connectionString, string driverClass = NormDriverClass, string prefix = null)
    {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
        configuration.Configure().SetProperty(ConnectionStringProperty, connectionString);
        configuration.Properties.Add(ConnectionDriverProperty, driverClass);
        configuration.Properties.Add("regionPrefix", prefix ?? "default");
        configuration.AddAssembly(typeof(Foo).Assembly);

        return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
```

I've set the query to cachable:

```
query.SetCacheable(true).SetCacheMode(CacheMode.Normal);
```

I get the following error every time

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException : Index was outside the bounds of the array.
at NHibernate.Type.TypeHelper.Disassemble(Object[] row, ICacheAssembler[] types, Boolean[] nonCacheable, ISessionImplementor session, Object owner)
at NHibernate.Cache.StandardQueryCache.Put(QueryKey key, ICacheAssembler[] returnTypes, IList result, Boolean isNaturalKeyLookup, ISessionImplementor session)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.PutResultInQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, IType[] resultTypes, IQueryCache queryCache, QueryKey key, IList result)
at NHibernate.Loader.Loader.ListUsingQueryCache(ISessionImplementor session, QueryParameters queryParameters, ISet`1 querySpaces, IType[] resultTypes)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.ListCustomQuery(ICustomQuery customQuery, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters, IList results)
at NHibernate.Impl.SessionImpl.List(NativeSQLQuerySpecification spec, QueryParameters queryParameters)
at NHibernate.Impl.SqlQueryImpl.List()
```

Thinking the cache provider was to blame, I switched back to

```
<property name="cache.provider_class">NHibernate.Cache.HashtableCacheProvider,NHibernate</property>
```

No change.

I removed the region prefix code, no change.

Setting "Use_query_cache" to false fixes the runtime exception but then no cache is used.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here. 
I've downloaded the source code and did a little bit of debugging and the problem seems to sit in core module.

I've created an [issue](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3311) on Jira and just realized someone else has done the [same](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-2961) few months ago.

Comment: I've worked through and it turns out public class CustomLoader : Loader
 {
  // Currently *not* cachable if autodiscover types is in effect (e.g. "select * ...")

should have tipped me off. 

That said, I've worked on it and it looks like I'll have a fix for this issue. It'll need more testing, but I'll leave another comment and link to the Github Fork with it.

Comment: @ClutchDude: Cool. Let me know cause I am still struggling with this issue.

Comment: I've got a preliminary fix finally done. I'll be cleaning it up and testing more next week. Once it's stable enough, I'll do a pull request.   https://github.com/Seakip18/nhibernate-core/tree/Branch_3.3.2GA_CacheFix